# from ._sparsetools import csr_tocsc, csr_tobsr, csr_count_blocks, \ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, scikit-image

I need your help please
When I wrote:

```
>>> from skimage import io
```

I get at the end the following:

```
from ._sparsetools import csr_tocsc, csr_tobsr, csr_count_blocks, \
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

How can I fix it? Any help would be appreciated

Comment: How did you install scipy?  Did you run its tests? I think this points to scipy and changed the tags.

Comment: To install scipy, i typed: python - m pip install scipy

Comment: No, i didn't run its tests, how to do it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9200923/2320035

Comment: When I run the test, I get at the end: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytest'

Comment: Thank you for your replies, but how can i solve these errors? Please help me :(

Comment: Reading the link should give you an idea. Install pytest (in  past: nose)

Comment: After installing pytest and running the test again, i get 8 warnings, 185 errors in 62.46 seconds :(

Comment: Did you try uninstalling and reinstalling scikit-image?

Comment: Thank you but I have already tried

Comment: I don't know which distribution of Python you are using, but this could be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32620691/error-importing-scipy-sparse-sparsetools

Comment: Thank you for the link you provided, i passed that error since I have installed msvcp120.dll

Comment: But this time I have another error: from ..color import rgb2gray
ImportError: cannot import name 'rgb2gray' from 'skimage.color' (C:\Users\user\A
ppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\skimage\color\__init_
_.py)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58443686/5591519

Answer (score 4):

**[Solution]** -

You need to install the C++ distribution for Visual Studio. Please click on this link -
[Download C++ re-distribution here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads) and Download **Visual Studio 2015, 2017 and 2019** according to your OS.

Once downloaded please install it and re-run your code.

Congratulations!! Your code is running green now.

Comment: Nice @Shivam Bharadwaj , I did it same way

Answer (score 2):

I believe I have solved your issue, as I encountered the same problem in a completely different way.

You need to update your windows C++ redistributable compiler.

To understand if this is the solution.

- Check what versions of microsoft C++ redistributable you have installed

  - if you're using windows 10 type apps and features into the start bar and scroll down to where it says microsoft visual C++ and look at the year. In my case I was using a version from 2010
- If you aren't running the latest version download microsoft visual studio 2017
- Select the visual studio community 2017

  - Once prompted to install specific packages, click on the menu item that says "individual components", it is located next to the menu item "Workloads"
  - Scroll down and look for **Visual C++ 2017 Redistributable Update**
  - Install that restart your machine
  - You'll be able to verify that this worked by running the following code in your console

---

```
import scipy
scipy.test('full')
```

*Note* for the above code to execute you'll need to install the pytest module

```
pip install pytest
```

Answer (score 1):

its may be a problem with your python idle version. you may using a 64 bit pc and having 32 bit python. please uninstall existing one and install 64 bit python

Answer (score 0):

Clearly installation is broken so reinstall scipy and numpy .if it does not solve then add this issue on git repository of scipy module.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem while using SciPy. I uninstalled the 32 bit version of Python and reinstalled 64 bit latest version. After doing so the error was no longer there.